# GemFire: start distributed system

Tags: gemfire

I want to start a distributed system over wan, but I got an exception when trying to start a remote member
I proceed like that :

> From server1:

- I start a locator (locator1)
- I start a server (server1)

> From another distant server:

- I connect to the cluster with:  connect --locator=@ip[port]
- I start another server but I got this exception exception

[click to view the Exception screen-shot when trying to start a remote member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe1tC.png)

How can I correct this exception?
And how can I start a member that belongs to a remote cluster in GemFire?

Answer (score 0):

The image doesn't help much, it just says that the member couldn't join the distributed system after 64077ms (probably due to a slow connection but can't be sure looking only at the stack trace), you need to look at the locator and server logs to check why the member couldn't join.

That said, if the cluster is composed of multiple members distributed across geographical distances with slower connections, it's better to use [WAN replication](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/topologies_and_comm/multi_site_configuration/chapter_overview.html) instead of a single cluster. Id' recommend a quick reading through [Topologies and Communication](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/topologies_and_comm/book_intro.html).

Cheers.